# Is “how I believe it works” okay?

Tags: grammar

I have a tendency to say:

> That’s how I believe it works.

Instead of:

> I believe that’s how it works.

Is it grammatical?

Comment: It is grammatical but your preferred version sounds less natural than the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but they have somewhat different meanings.

"That's how I believe it works" emphasizes the *how **I** believe*.  It implies something like "That's how *I* believe it works *but other people believe it works differently.*"

In "I believe that's how it works" the implication is that you are not completely certain that you're correct about *how it works*.  There's no implication that other people think differently.